# What exactly is the meaning of the text of Doxology in the concluding part of Catholic Eucharistic prayer?

Tags: catholicism

With these solemn words, the priest ends the Eucharistic prayer at the centre of which is the event of the consecration.

> Through him, and with him, and in him,
>   O God, almighty Father,
>   in the unity of the Holy Spirit,
>   all glory and honour is yours,
>   for ever and ever.

What exactly is the meaning of this and what is the interpretation of this in Catholic theology?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of several different valid ways to take it:

1. ***Through*** Jesus as intercessor, the glory and honor is the Father's.
2. ***With*** Jesus as brother alongside us, the glory and honor is the Father's.
3. ***In*** Jesus, the Church being his body, the glory and honor is the Father's.

All of this is one action with the Holy Spirit (as Jesus acts in unity with the other person of the Trinity) who acts in and with all of us (we are unified as we act under inspiration of the Trinity).